# Ogre3D Basic Framework issue on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, netbeans, ubuntu, ogre3d

I have been trying to learn to use Ogre3D and have gotten to the stage where I want to start something more serious than the examples it comes with so I found and copied the [Basic Ogre Framework](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/Basic_Ogre_Framework)

I am using Ubuntu 9.10, but have compiled Ogre 1.7 from the Ogre3D website, I am using the Netbeans 6.8 IDE with the c++ plugin.

The Basic Ogre Framework Demo App compiles and runs, but gets to the main loop where is checks to see if the Render Window is active, otherwise it calls `sleep(1000);`

The if statement that is checking `if(OgreFramework::getSingletonPtr()->m_pRenderWnd->isActive())` is always returning false, despite specifically setting the `m_pRenderWnd->setActive(true);`

From reading the forum posts related to it, nobody else is having this issue, but they are primarily using windows or Mac.

Is there issues with Ogre3D on Ubuntu, or is it possibly a problem with the autogenerated makefiles that netbeans is generating?

Comment: I think there is just some library weirdness on my current ubuntu install so I am going to do a clean install and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured the application to use the correct video drivers for your system? Since you're on ubuntu you'll need to use OpenGL. I found some drivers didn't work on some systems when using Ogre.

Comment: yes, I get the window, the app runs but it just sits there dumbly and wont accept keyboard or mouse input.

Comment: As a test I would comment out the if statement. Assuming it's incorrectly telling you the window is not active then this would let it continue on. The best thing to do would be to trace into the isActive() function to see why it thinks it's not active.